# JavaScript nested JSON of same name

Tags: javascript, json

```
{"func" : "sprint", "nest" : {"func" : "walk", "nest": {"func" : "run"}}}
```

Above is an example of a nested Json object.

These can range from a single object to many nested objects. I want to call method based on the most nested object to the least nested.

In the example there is 2 nest values. How can I call the last one to the first in this order

```
func : run
```

than

```
func : walk
```

than

```
func : sprint
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take a recursive [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) for the nested object.

```js
function depthFirst(object) {
    return [...(object.nest ? depthFirst(object.nest) :[]), object.func];
}

var data = { func: "sprint", nest: { func: "walk", nest: { func: "run" } } };

console.log(depthFirst(data));
```

Comment: I haven't seen something like this before, Do you have a good link so I can read up depthFirst, Also in the return statement what is the 3 periods for?

Comment: [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) returns the items of [iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#Built-in_iterables) as parameters.